# How do I call a PHP function without it redirecting to the php file?

Tags: php, html

I have a webform that calls a PHP function to write its contents to a file when the submit button is clicked. But I want the file to be written "in the background." That is, it should write the file, but the webpage should not change. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need to use some client-side code like JavaScript.

Answer (score 3):

Good news: Yes it is!

The easiest way would be using the popular `jQuery` library. They have a function to post form data to a php file without refreshing the page.

It is commonly referred as "AJAX",
you can find tons of documents on google, have fun :]

Answer (score 0):

Check the example at [jQuery's](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) reference

Answer (score 0):

Ajax is the solution. [Here's](http://www.ajaxprojects.com/ajax/tutorialdetails.php?itemid=9) an example of sending data with ajax (chat application)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.jensbits.com/2009/10/04/jquery-ajax-and-jquery-post-form-submit-examples-with-php/

Use jQuery $.post() or $.ajax() to run your script "in the background".
This way you can call any url (script) you want without changing page content (or you can do something with the page if you need to).